# Android ListView SQL separator

Tags: android, listview

I currently have an external class which runs query from database, and returns Year and Month. in format of: 04/2003, 04/2004 etc..
Then it puts everything into List and returns it into main class where list gets asisgned to ListViewer. So I have two ways of listing everything:
User clicks on month in list, then is given choice of years. 
or
How do I make it to be separated like, when user selects specific month it gives list like:

```
======2010======
Dec
Jan
March
etc..
======2011======
Dec
Jan
March
etc...
======2012======
Dec
Jan
March
etc..
```

So basically how do I make a ListViewer to automatically split or separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Map for this:

1. Create a Map> which maps year -> list of months.
2. Display the years on the firs listview and the corresponding months on the second listview.